# call a $.getJSON and sending URL parameter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a page with the following URL **test.php?city=Paris** and  I have a php script (getData.php) which executes a SQL request and return a JSON object. To execute my request I need the parameter city in my URL. I call the getData.php script like this :

```
var ville = "<?php echo $_GET['ville']?>";
$.getJSON("bat/getData.php", {ville: ville}, function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

I don't think that is the best way to send the URL parameter to my php script.
What do you think?

Comment: That is correct, except that you need to JS-escape the string literal.

Comment: not sure to understand what do you mean by "you need to JS-escape the string literal"

Comment: What if `$_GET['ville']` has a `"`  or `\​`?

Comment: @user1128939 JSON encoding takes care of all the escaping for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should not echo arbitrary data into a script.  You have opened yourself up to cross-site scripting attacks.

You can get around the problem by JSON-encoding your data, which is compatible with JavaScript.

```
var ville = <?php echo json_encode($_GET['ville']); ?>;
```

Comment: seems that is not work very well.... var ville = <?php json_encode($_GET['ville']); ?>;
           console.log(ville); nothing is echoed in the console.

Comment: @user1128939 Sorry, I was missing an `echo` in there.  Try now.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with passing parameters as part of the query string.

But implementing a little REST service is probably more elegant. Based on your current implementation the REST service would provide the following resources:

```
GET /cities/{cityname}
```

Example:

```
GET /cities/paris
```